# ansible check lineinfile for string fails

Tags: ansible

Really hoping someone is able to help, I've got this task, that checks if string XYZ exists in a log

if it doesn't exists, it should fail (ignore_errors: yes) then kick another task, however, even when it fails, it skips the other task

```
 - name: check if file is empty
       lineinfile:
          path: /path/to/log.log
          line: "XYZ"
          state: present
       check_mode: yes
       register: exists
       failed_when: exists is changed
       ignore_errors: yes

     - name: send mail
       when: exists is not changed
       mail:
          from: mail@123.com
          subject: xyz
          body: No xyz found
          to:
           - John Doe <john.doe@123.com>
          cc: Marie Smith <marie.smit@123.com>

     - name: read files
       when: exists is changed
       do abc...
```

the issue is that when the file is empty and doesn't have XYZ, it still fails, but skips the mail send and carries on with the read files task

```
TASK [check if file is empty] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

fatal: [server123]: FAILED! => {"backup": "", "changed": true, "failed_when_result": true, "msg": "line added"}

...ignoring



TASK [send mail] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

skipping: [server123]



TASK [read files] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

changed: [server123]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your expectation correctly then you can achieve the result using `grep` and `command` module also. Here is a sample:

```
- name: check if file is empty
  command: grep -xq 'XYZ' /path/to/log.log
  register: exists
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: send mail
  mail:
    from: mail@123.com
    subject: xyz
    body: No xyz found
    to:
      - John Doe <john.doe@123.com>
    cc: Marie Smith <marie.smit@123.com>
  when: exists.failed

- name: read files
  debug:
    msg: do abc...
  when: not exists.failed
```

You can adjust the grep logic that suits.